# Veracrypt encryption safety

Tags: encryption

Is it really safe, or can someone brute force or get the files decrypted?

Is there any way to protect against it? Maybe better encryption or a script that destroys the files if someone tries to decrypt them?

Comment: You can ask for product recommendation here https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @KrishnaPandey This question is NOT a good fit for Software Recommendations SE. Please don't send people there unless their question fulfills the [question quality requirements](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) over there. That site is moderated even harder than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it really safe

Veracrypt like most security technologies are in a constant state of cat and mouse. There isn't really a "safe" only "secure for now" and they have been keeping up on this to the best of my knowledge. In 2016 an audit was completed, you can read about it [here on OSTIFs page](https://ostif.org/the-veracrypt-audit-results/) and was the most recent audit of it that I know of, I could be behind on this one.

> can someone brute force or get the files decrypted?

If your password is sufficiently short, yes. If it isn't it wouldn't be likely.

> Is there any way to protect against it?

Make sure your password is strong. More than 20 chars, uppercase and lowercase, special chars... you know, basic stuff. If you're ***really*** paranoid about it, operate on your containers in an air gapped machine and transfer any data you need through yourself, or another method that doesn't leave the containers exposed.

> Maybe better encryption or a script that destroys the files if someone tries to decrypt them?

Don't attempt this, If you have to ask you can't implement it, plus you would need a very "touchy" method to distinguish between you, the normal user attempting a decryption, and the attacker, also attempting the same decryption.

To sum it up, veracrypt should be fine. Of course, you give no details of the threats you are trying to mitigate or the environment you are operating in, so it's difficult to give you more accurate advice. But if it's just general concern, veracrypt seems to be a good choice right now. When encrypted volumes are in play, adversaries seem to choose to attempt other means of data retrieval that don't rely on cracking the volume. So I'd say that's a point in its favor.